# Are edits that simply apply bold formatting to names of programming languages desirable?

Tags: discussion, support

A few edits like this one turned up in the review queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10645389

I clicked skip on them because I wasn't sure what to do.

My gut reaction is, if the words are already capitalized, then that is clear, and bold highlighting represents "no improvement whatsoever".

Is that the consensus view? Or is bold highlighting on names of programming languages / branded programming software a desirable edit?

Comment: @approxiblue: Ok, so if I think an edit is bad but I'm not sure, then I should flag the edit and let a mod handle it? Does that result in me eventually being notified of the resolution, so I know in the future if it should be "reject" or "accept"?

Comment: No notification in that case, you'll have to check back yourself. If you're unsure, just skip and let others review, no need to escalate to mods. In this particular review though, it's a clear reject (no improvement).