# User adding excessive bolding in otherwise good edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Just ran across a new user who likes to add strategic bolding to posts he edits.  Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12858308

We've had questions before about editors who do nothing *but* add useless formatting (e.g., [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313115/are-edits-that-simply-apply-bold-formatting-to-names-of-programming-languages-de) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294206/user-being-encouraged-to-insert-inappropriate-formatting)), but this one tends to make real improvements, too.  (A little happy with the blockquotes, but otherwise correct and thorough.)  And the bolding isn't random; if I thought adding bold fonts would help readability, that's how I would have done it.

But I think the edits should have been rejected, or at least reject-and-edited to remove the bolding.  If nothing else, it's rudely overriding the author's personal style--lower on the scale than changing someone's bracing style, but on there.  And I think it's doing more harm than good, readability-wise.

I would hesitate to [remove](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262085/use-of-bolding-in-a-question) excessive bolding if the original author used it, but editors definitely shouldn't be *adding* it.  Is there a policy on this?  Something we can point to as a counterweight to all those reviewers who approved the edits?  Should the reviewers be penalized?

Comment: **Bold all the Thingz!** ... that is awful and doesn't make the post easier to read, at all. As a matter of fact, it makes it worse... Just roll back or reject and edit...

Comment: Furthermore instead of **bolding** everything i saw in SO that most often we use `this` for readability. If the user continue after some rejected edits, then a little warn is appriopriated.

Comment: "lower on the scale than changing someone's bracing style"... not even! I don't mind bracing style that much, but I wouldn't want my posts to look like a pinball machine.

Comment: `This` isn't supposed to be used for emphasis, but for fixed names like class names (e.g. "I have a `UIWebView`")

Comment: Have you already contacted the user? Often, these new editors don't even know that excessive boldfacing is bad. And as long as the robo-reviewers are approving it all, neither do these editors get a chance to learn :-(

Comment: Is **fixed** now

Comment: So @S.L.Barth what you're saying is that robo reviewers might embolden the editors who make this kind of bold style choice?

Comment: @the**B** :-) And now I suddenly realize what the **B** in your username stands for!

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I have now.  I referred them to this Q/A.

Comment: Regardless of the quality of the edit, that was a **terrible** review. I'm disappointed that 3 users approved and *nobody* rejected.

Comment: #boldlivesmatter Maybe someone is going for the editing badge?

Comment: @Kev Great edit title :)

Comment: Typographically speaking, boldface is for advertising. It's greatly overused on the Web in general, and by the computer industry in general. Occasional italics for emphasis are OK but not semi-random strings of boldface. The suggested edit is a case study in how not to use it.

Comment: Almost all of his rep seems to come from **edits**.

Comment: @Adnan: Please check this question about adding formatting.

Comment: @ShaunakD: Good, we need more people working on improving posts!

Comment: The reviewers who unanimously approved this nonsense ought to be shot.

Answer (score 23):

Excessive bolding/emphasis makes posts less readable than posts with none of it.  Bold is supposed to draw attention to important parts of the post, but it's also rather distracting.  IMO, bolding too much stuff makes any attempt I have at reading the post really hard.  I'd personally reject almost any suggestion that over-styles a post because that makes things harder to read.

If the suggestion fixed other egregious problems that took a lot of effort (like code formatting, rampant typos) then I'd consider approving/improving the suggestion.  **If the improvement from the edit is much greater than the distractions from the bold, then approving/improving it is fine**.  But in the example suggestion linked in the question, the distraction of the bold far outweighs the grammar fixes.

Comment: So what would you recommend if the improvement from the edit is much greater than the distractions from the bold?

Comment: I'd recommend "Improve edit" which implicitly approve it as well.  Then you can keep all the good work achieved while pulling back some of the excess bold/formatting.

Comment: @ryanyuyu ...and if you can spare the time, add a comment below the post, addressing the editor, and explaining your improvement of their edit.

Comment: Yes, once the edit has been approved, you can ping the editor of the post.  You won't get an autosuggest for editors, but you can still ping them by username with a leading `@`.

Comment: There are plenty of edits from that user that do fix a lot of problems; thus my ambivalence.  In fact, other than the bolding and some inappropriate blockquoting, he generally does everything I would do, which is rare for a <2k user.  And I did ping him, and he acknowledged, so we're cool there.

Comment: **Bold** can **also** be **used** as **an** artistic **medium** like **in** this **zebra** comment **.**

Comment: What about [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30687848), there are few changes and I thought it was Ok, but got rejected