# The question wizard didn't carry over my post body from the Description to the Review step

Tags: support, asking-questions, ask-question-wizard-2018

I am trying to ask a question with the new question UI (very,very slick), but I've run into a very weird problem. When I click the review button on the description page, it gives me a blank textbox for the body.

The description page-

> [image: description]

The review page-

> [image]

The title's there, but none of the stuff I typed in the previous page. When I try submitting it without entering anything in the body, it says the body is empty. I don't get it.

I have tried creating another question to test it (For the sake of my SO karma, I won't click post), and the review section displays properly there-

The question body-

> [image: random question]

The review page-

> [image: Clicking post is obviously not an option.]

I don't know how to reproduce this, so I'm not tagging it as a bug.

And I've just noticed that the preview didn't load for the faulty question.

Comment: The black background on the title and body text fields seem... off. Are you using any browser extensions? If yes, have you tried disabling all, then enabling one by one to check if something is interfering?

Comment: Can  you share browser and OS and their versions.

Comment: The browser is Firefox 64, and the os is Pop_os. The black bg is because of a WM theme, not any extensions

Comment: One thing you could try is subtractive debugging: cut away parts of your question text until the problem disappears. Then restore the part you last cut away, and try removing other pieces, or smaller parts of the same piece, until you're left with a minimal example that demonstrates the bug, but which you cannot make any shorter or simpler. Then post it here.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen StackOverflow actually introduced that feature (triple backticks for code blocks) 8 Jan 2019 (19 days ago) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks/322000#322000

Comment: @Ferrybig: Oh, wow! That's awesome, and I totally missed it!

Comment: It seems to be a one-off thing, I ended up skipping the guide and just typed out my question in the review screen to make sure it wouldn't happen again.

Comment: @Ferrybig I swear I've used that prior to that date...

Comment: @Ferrybig I'm jealous, you got 6 upvotes for your comment, [but I got zero for the same](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378962/should-we-approve-suggested-edits-that-change-to-four-spaces-code-formatting#comment663442_378962). ;)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Not on SO you haven't!

Comment: @Cœur It's not the same, yours is a low-quality, link-only comment with incorrect information :D ;) (posted on the 17th and saying 10 days ago means on the 7th, but it was on the 8th, right?)