# Support: user on an edit spree

Tags: support, edits

I have done some edit reviews today and noticed that user `HashRocketSyntax` is on an [edit spree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5739514/hashrocketsyntax?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) to change many Python questions, new and old, to systematically use Python syntax highlighting.

Some of his edits are good, and while syntax highlighting is nice, in most cases he is touching questions that don't need to be updated.

Is it possible to contact this user to recommend editing only when editing is really needed, not just systematically for a small presentation detail?

Comment: IMO I don't see a problem with this so long as this user isn't ignoring other problems that could be fixed at the same time.

Comment: I am a sort of surprised he is still able to edit with all the ones that where rejected on the first page

Comment: The edits I see don't add syntax highlighting at all. The questions are already tagged with the language. The syntax highlighting is already in place.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378962/should-we-approve-suggested-edits-that-change-to-four-spaces-code-formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no rule that says you can't edit old posts (to my knowledge). In fact, you even get a badge for editing a post that's been inactive for 6 months, so the system seems to encourage it.

If the edit is good (e.g. improves the post), then it is fine. Ideally it should fix every problem with the post, but everybody doesn't catch everything all of the time. In my opinion, an edit that adds syntax highlighting where there was none (or worse, where there was incorrect syntax highlighting) is objectively an improvement, however small. I haven't looked at the edits you're referencing, to be clear; I'm not not making a judgment on those, just on the *kind* of edits you describe here.

However, this user appears to have had 8 edit suggestions rejected in the span of an hour or so. The Help Center does point out that:

> Additionally, any user who submits many rejected edits will be banned from suggesting further edits for 7 days.

I'm not sure what the limit is (it's most likely intentionally secret), but if I had to guess, I'd say 8 rejections in such a short time would trigger said ban.

Likewise, I believe there is a limit on the number of edit suggestions you can do per day (and a smaller limit on the number of edit suggestions you can have active at any one time).

Hopefully the user will have taken notice and either slow down or work to provide more substantive edits in the future. If that's not enough for you, you can always leave a comment under one of the user's posts (or the post they edited last, as they'd be notified then by @-ing them) giving some guidance... just make sure you don't run afoul of the guidelines for editing as put forth by the Help Center.

Comment: Looking at two of the pending edits and they are just changing code formating  from the 4 spaces format to the tripple backtick one

Comment: @JoeW Then those are pointless edits, and should be rejected.

Comment: There's no per day limit, just an at-one-time limit for edits, unless I missed a change.

Comment: I think there was a limit at a certain amount of posts per day (I don't remember the number, possibly 50?) for users without the editing privilege. Beyond that, the only limit is that you can't have more than 5 pending edits

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I see the spree stopped, maybe the ban took effect. As the primary message, what I'm taking here is that I should review each edit for its own merit, and trust the ban to kick in when there is a problem.

Comment: As for editing old posts, I can't find it now, but I remember reading advice that said editing old posts had the side effect of bringing them back front on the issues lists (when sorted by activity), so they should only be done if a significant improvement was done. I've taken from that advice that typos or small presentation changes should not be done on old posts, only sizable edits. As as result, I tend to accept tiny or small edits on recent posts but reject them on older ones. Do you agree with that approach?

Comment: @joanis If someone is editing a ton of stuff all at once, yes, it's bad because it can flood the tag view of that tag with outdated questions (though I also think it's not too much to ask users to put some effort into reading dates and clicking a few buttons to get to the questions they want to see). However, 1-3 questions at at a time (e.g. a day) is not problematic even for low-traffic tags.