# What's the difference between the two code formatting styles (code-fences vs indented blocks) regarding syntax highlighting?

Tags: discussion, edits, markdown, code

I have been using code fences to highlight my code in SO

> ```javascript
>
> ```

Recently I have noted that my code is being edited and the below syntax is being used

> <!-- lang-js -->

I have seen code fences being used in several platforms to highlight code. Is there a reason for changing from code fences to the other syntax?

The post [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) provides an explanation of how to format your code, unfortunately what I am looking for is how the two syntax highlighting differ, that is why edit to change from one syntax highlighting to the other

Comment: Aside from the post you linked yesterday, were there more instances of this happening? There is no practical reason to change from one code formatting style to the other. And if that's the only thing being edited in the post, it's a pointless edit.

Comment: For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64359075/revisions), the change was not only in code formatting style, but they actually added the language so the proper highlighting was applied. In the original revision, syntax-highlighting wasn't used.

Comment: Strongly related (but not a dupe): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378962/6296561

Comment: Thanks @Zoe I can see in the post it says `Edits like those should be rejected...` But How to reject a code edit if it is approved before I even get a chance to have a look at it?

Comment: @OwenKelvin You can rollback the edit. But please make sure it's actually worth rolling it back. Check the edit in my other comment, and you'll see the edit actually improved the post (change of code formatting style notwithstanding).

Comment: If you're the OP of the post, you can force reject the edit after the fact, provided you didn't approve it originally of course. In the remaining cases, you can roll it back, but you should mod flag instead. Mods can also force reject after the fact provided there's no revisions after the offending edit, as well as impose an edit ban if necessary.

Comment: There is no difference between the two code-formatting styles. Use whichever suits you.

Comment: Ideally `<!-- lang-js -->` should _not_ be used as that form of language declaration has been depracated, `\`\`\`javascript` should be preferred, although isn't mandated

Comment: @yivi that's not technically entirely true. `<!-- language: whatever -->` is deprecated and will be removed eventually. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark

Comment: @Zoe It's technically true in the sense that there is no difference in the resulting output. Yup, it's deprecated. And the OP already uses the preferred style. If for some reason they want to use the older style, it will be automatically converted the day SO decides to stop supporting it (or break thousands and thousands of posts).

Comment: So basically `indented blocks` is deprecated and using it faces the risk of breaking the day SO decides to stop supporting it

Comment: No, indented blocks are gonna keep working, but at some point in the future, there will be no way to specify what language to use for the block. The only way to set a language is through the automatic detection system, which IIRC only relies on tags

Comment: If the tag doesn't provide a cue, then the auto detection system also tries to "read" your code to determine what language it is, and highlights accordingly. The results vary, dramatically.

Comment: Nothing like a bit of progress; looking forward to all those vb.net/sqlserver tagged questions where everything is highlighted as TSQL

Comment: @Nick that looks like an actual answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to the deprecation [MattDMo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402162/157247) pointed out [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402162/157247) (and [Nick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402109/whats-the-difference-between-the-two-code-formatting-styles-code-fences-vs-ind?cb=1#comment802483_402109) in the comments), one small point:

Your two examples aren't *quite* equivalent. The precise equivalent of `<!-- language: lang-js -->` with code fences is ```` ```lang-js ```` (with the `lang-` prefix). ```` ```js ```` says "use the default formatter for the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag" (because `js` is an alias for `javascript`), but `<!-- language: lang-js -->` tells the site explicitly to format the code as JavaScript, without referring to the tag. It doesn't matter for JavaScript, but it does for some other tags, like [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript).

Details:

The token following the ```` ``` ```` in code fences is a **tag** identifier unless you have a `lang-` prefix on it. It tells the site to use the default formatting for that tag, it doesn't refer to a specific language directly. To do that, use the `lang-` prefix.

It matters for some tags, like [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript), because the default formatting for [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) posts is **JavaScript**, not TypeScript ([at least for now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354679/please-enable-highlight-jss-support-for-typescript)). So if you do this:

````
```typescript
codeHere();
```
````

you'll get JavaScript formatting. This gives you TypeScript formatting:

````
```lang-typescript
codeHere();
```
````

It can matter, particularly with function overloads. Here's what a ```` ```typescript ```` block looks like on SO (an image because the tag marker doesn't work on MSO):

[image: TypeScript code (mis)formatted as JavaScript]

Here's a ```` ```lang-typescript ```` block:

```typescript
function exampleOverload(a: number): number;
function exampleOverload(a: number[]): number[];
function exampleOverload(a: number | number[]): number | number[] {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        return a.map(v => v * 2);
    }
    return a * 2;
}
```

Comment: *It can matter, particularly with function overloads* Maybe you can demonstrate here.

Comment: @TheMaster - I was worried it was going too far into the TypeScript thing. But I've added an example from the [linked feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354679/please-enable-highlight-jss-support-for-typescript).

Comment: This is... kinda ground-breaking. I've *never* seen this referenced *anywhere* on the site before, and if accurate it helps explain some odd behaviors I've noticed. How did you learn this?

Comment: @zcoop98 - It's documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting): *"You can use either one of the [supported language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), like `lang-cpp` or `lang-sql`, or you can specify a tag, and the syntax highlighting language associated with this tag will be used."* I didn't know it either until Martijn Pieters pointed it out to me fairly recently.

Answer (score 8):

Visually, there is no difference when the Markdown is rendered into HTML and displayed in your browser. However, as @Nick [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402109/whats-the-difference-between-the-two-code-formatting-styles-code-fences-vs-ind?cb=1#comment802483_402109) in the comments above, the `<!-- language: lang-whatever -->` directive has been deprecated with the [switch to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) and may be subject to removal at some point in the future. So, for forwards compatibility, using code fences is the preferred way now.

It should be noted that edits changing the old language directive to code fences are not desirable, *unless* significant other improvements have been made to the post as well.