# Code blocks: spaces vs fences

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, code-formatting

Recently I've been seeing quite a number of "suggested edits" that do *nothing* other than change a perfectly valid "indented code block" (using 4 spaces) to a code block enclosed by fences (```). Sometimes this includes a language specifier, but not always.

I tend to reject these as "no improvement" unless the language specifier makes a difference.

I wonder if this is the right thing to do.  It is not clear to me if one style is preferred over the other: The code formatting tip on the "ask a question" form only mentions fences, but the [editing-help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) mentions spaces first.

So, my question:

**Is there a preferred method for writing code blocks?** Should we all start using fences instead of spaces, because this allows us to specify the language?

[This meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402162) says:

> ... edits changing the old language directive to code fences are not desirable, unless ...

Comment: Unless the change is specifically adding a language specifier, as the syntax highlighting is wrong, I see no benefit either. Certainly I would mark them as "no improvement" in a review. If, however, the language *should* have been specified and wasn't (and I include`none` as choice there as some text should **not** have highlighting), I might reject the edit and edit myself to add the fences with the language, while making other improvements.

Comment: I'd hold off on all those edits using Skip as the syntax-highlighter has been [completely removed from all suggested edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408993/12695027). You can't see if it improves the post or not anymore.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378962/6296561), and potentially a duplicate if the question is only about edit handling.

Comment: Sometimes OP's code is formatted very weirdly, so I plug it into a formatter and paste it back in. This removes the 4 leading spaces, so I just use ``` instead.

Comment: @aheze Just as easy to highlight and press the code button `{}` or press Ctrl+K (on Windows), no?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I didn't know you can do that, I pretty much never press the buttons at the top... I'll try that next time, thanks!

Comment: I think we should consider why these edits are being made in the first place. After all, the delimiter style is not obvious just by looking at the rendered post, so it's not like someone with strong opinions could be _bothered_ just by the sight of a "wrongly" formatted post. I suspect these edits are an attempt to farm reputation, especially because they are nearly guaranteed to meet the 6-character threshold. I expect this practice to continue as long as there is an incentive to do it.

Comment: This is a dupe of several different questions: [Should we approve suggested edits that change ``` to four spaces code formatting or vice versa?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378962), [What is the preferrred method for formatting code?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387765), [Why are people using 4 space-indent to post code?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392061), [What's the difference between the two code formatting styles regarding syntax highlighting?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402109), [Why are posts edited to change the code formatting markers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407744)

Comment: We would normally list all of those questions in the duplicate box, because, taken together, that set covers all of the ground of this question. However, a good answer was posted to this question, which fits best on a *specific* one of those duplicates. In order to move that answer to the correct question, I had to merge this with that specific original question, and that means it shows up only as a duplicate of that one question. That question answers the bolded, "Is there a preferred method for writing code blocks?", but see the dupes in the comment above for relation to suggested edits.