# Why did I get a one-year ban on all review categories for making mistakes in one category?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I have made 4 mistakes on "Suggested Edits" review category which I still don't know why they were wrong; however I take the full responsibility of them. Because of these mistakes, I have been banned for a whole year in all the review categories.

First of all, I wish to know why my reviews were wrong and then even if all of them were wrong, wouldn't it have made more sense if I'd gotten banned on "Suggested Edits" category and not all of them?

[Review1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30642869)

[Review2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30664842)

[Review3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30712845)

[Review4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30713505)

Comment: Because your ability to review is all linked.  Why did you make so many mistakes a year long suspension was necessary? You had to have been review suspended in the past to earn yourself a year long suspension. In every one of those reviews you approve unnecessary formatting changes to the contribution, and in at least one case (due to the reject and edit from a moderator) approved an incomplete edit proposal.

Comment: Well, to answer the question: because technically, there's only "review ban"... no "suggested edit review ban", or "first answer review ban", or any specific review ban...

Comment: For example, Review 1 is code only formatting and does not improve anything.

Comment: @TGrif not only that, review 1, 2, and 4 has code formatting changes that introduces unnecessary indentation. Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378968/6296561

Comment: That was only one of your mistakes. Use the time off to find out what good edits actually are. Hint: keeping "thanks" in a post is not useful.

Comment: [A reference for the "thanks" part](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: The suggestion in review 2 had actual improvements. Though offset by the unnecessary (relatively harmless) indentation. Much worse edit suggestions exist. I don't think that should lead to a ban.

Comment: Banning is wrong, we should find a better solution to teach better reviewing. Banning is a harsh punishment

Comment: @nbk You mean like teaching people what Stack Overflow is and what it isn't? We have an astounding success there. People don't care that their way is wrong as long as they can got that path unhindered. That is why there are those bans. People should actually use that time to learn how to do it correctly. Then they wouldn't need multiple bans to learn just now that meaningless edits shouldn't be approved.

Comment: @nbk - At what point do we send a message that approving non-substantial or unnecessary edits isn’t appropriate? There has to be something that happens when unnecessary edits are approved

Comment: @PeterMortensen The issue with the indentation might be less about harm and more about how annoyingly frequent it’s become for people to add code fences around something already formatted as code.

Comment: @RobertLongson I did pay attention, but approved edits which I truly didn't know should not have been allowed. It was a mistake caused by not knowing facts, not by not paying attention.

Comment: I must say that the title question is a great question on it's own, too bad it got polluted a little bit by the secondary question about specific review items. This is why you should only ask one question at a time, even on meta.

Comment: A 1-year ban seems quite harsh, I agree. I would expect a duration that long only for vandalism or for some kind of abuse.

Comment: @ayhan bans generally double in length so to get a 1 year ban you usually need to have learned nothing from your prior 6 month, 3 month, 6 week, 3 week bans. Is it so harsh to stop you for longer and longer if you can't or won't learn?

Comment: Or to grab your attention to say "Hey! You're doing badly and we need you to know that"

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I think an exponential scheme is too harsh and overall harmful for the site.

Comment: @ayhan hope you're equally keen to clean the mess up that poor reviewers leave behind.

Comment: @Nick - While the year suspension is likely connected to grabbing the attention of the author. I have no doubt, previous attempts/suspension have happened.

Comment: @RobertLongson I believe a system focused on guidance rather than punishment would have a positive contribution to the site, irrespective of my involvement.

Comment: @ayhan there's plenty of guidance. Nobody wants to read it is the problem.

Comment: @iminiki, the moderator who imposed the original suspension, has shortened it.  Please use those few days to spend a bit of time reading through meta to try and better understand how reviews are expected to work.

Comment: I don't understand anyone saying any review ban is "harsh". Reviewing is unpaid voluntary help. If the what the person is doing isn't helpful, then they can be prevented from doing it any more. It's not a punishment.

Comment: @ayhan Part of the reason the bans get so long is that sometimes people spend a very long time away from the site. You can miss a 3 week ban if you don't visit for a month. They're trying to make sure people see that there was a problem.

Comment: @BSMP It's no longer the case that people will miss the review suspension notification. It used to be the case, but how things work was changed by SE a while back. At this point, if a review suspension is imposed, either automatically or by a moderator, then the user is informed about it and shown the suspension message (which describes what the issue was) the next time they go to the review queues, even if they don't go to the review queues during the time the review suspension is in place. Thus, extremely long review suspensions are no longer needed to be sure the user sees the notice.

Comment: @Makyen It shows as a small notice at the top of the review dropdown menu, and as a banner notification at the top of reviews until the user clicks the "got it" button..... okay?, people will click through that as quickly as they click through audit success notifications.. This is still _easily_ miss-able and to say "no longer the case" and "no longer needed" is naïve.

Answer (score 16):

> First of all, I wish to know why my reviews were wrong

Reviews 1, 2, and 4 unnecessarily change to code fences and introduce bad indentation. Review 1 *only* does this, making it the most useless and clearly rejectable in this batch.

Review 4 additionally introduces [unnecessary code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/6296561), as well as having otherwise minor changes. Review 3 [ignored fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/6296561) and  inlining the image, and overall doesn't address the actual problems of the post. In particular:

> I've question

Isn't a correct way to say "I have a question". Same with "I've a table" (which I ironically missed in my first sweep while editing. Whoops). Incidentally, "I have a question" is additionally removable as fluff, because it doesn't add anything to the post. The edit overall is very superficial, with several bad changes. [As a reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing),

> **Edits are expected to be substantial** and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - **To fix grammar and spelling mistakes**
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without *changing* that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

---

Review 2 also ignored fluff, and combined with the unnecessary indentation it introduces, the actual improvements don't outweigh the bad stuff it does. This applies to all edits; if the edit does have some objective improvements, but also includes bad changes, it's a matter of whether the good outweighs the bad. While unrelated to any of the changes made in any of the edits, [this post is very relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327175/6296561) to the good outweighing the bad.

> wouldn't it have made more sense if I'd gotten banned on "Suggested Edits" category and not all of them?

That's not technically possible at this time. You're either banned in none, or all. There is an exception related to flags, though; if you get flag banned, you're blocked from certain queues. However, since flag bans are fully automatic (read: mods have 0 involvement in their instatement or removal), this cannot be considered a single queue ban. There's also several non-flagging ways to get banned from queues where flags are that central, so even if manual flag bans were possible, this would often be an inappropriate use of the ban.

Answer (score 12):

When you're banned we want you to stop and consider why. We don't want you to just move on to making a mess elsewhere in the other review queues because you're equally unaware of what you're supposed to do there.

Take this time to understand the purpose of the review queues. They are all different. Look at some posts here on Meta where other people have complained about being banned in other queues.
Do you understand why they were?

Take a time out and be better in all queues when you return.

Answer (score 11):

Approving the edits in 1, 2 and 4 is a serious problem **because of the wrong indentation alone.**

It's a common editing mistake that the editor design contributes towards because there's no obvious way to dendent a block, see this old feature request [Add increase/decrease tab indent buttons to the editor toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8144)

Inexperienced editors end up submitting such edit suggestions because they don't find a way to revert their mistake or aren't aware to begin with that wrong indentation is a problem. A reviewer should either correct the wrong indentation or reject the edit because of it.

And why is wrong indentation such a big problem? Because it:

1. reduces code readability,
2. messes up overall left-align formatting,
3. causes extra work for the next editor who will have to correct it,
4. might cause a horizontal scroll bar to appear under the code block that might otherwise not be needed.