# Please help me understand this declined flag

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, declined-flags

I flagged [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25587151) for moderator attention as it seems to me like a bad edit which should not have been suggested or approved. To my surprise, the flag got declined with a generic "*a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it.*"

This was the content of the flag I raised about the editor (not the OP):

> IMHO this edit (stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25587151) should not have been approved. Unfortunately, quite a few of this user's edits are like this

Can someone explain to me why I was wrong here? I generally consider myself to be aware of what is considered a good or bad edit and I would have rejected this one for sure. I suspended my reviewing activity until I feel confident in making the right choices again and I think understanding why this edit is considered good by a mod would help me.

Comment: There are hundreds of incorrect reviews in the Suggested Edits queue. Flag for mod attention only if a user has approved/rejected incorrectly too many reviews.

Comment: Yes, you would have rejected this and over reviewers should too, but OP has their own review right for edits on own posts and what do you think a mod should do there? Review-ban them although they don't have (standard) review rights anyway?

Comment: I'd like to know the exact flag message and what you'd expect the outcome since that was approved by the OP. The only reviewer did reject the edit but was overturned by OP...

Comment: @double-beep I see. However, looking through the first page of reviews of this guy I found [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25592578) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25592860) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25592594) [weird](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25587205) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25539171).

Comment: @AndrewT. *declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it* I think the editor is not editing when necessary but when possible to gain rep. Not sure what should be done in such a case. I just thought I'd bring it to the attention of a mod.

Comment: I mean, your custom flag message, not the mod's response. Did you also state that the user had a history of superficial edits? There are more than hundreds (or even thousands?) flags daily, mods don't have time to investigate each case more than what the flags tell.

Comment: @AndrewT. Oh, I'm sorry. Here you go: *IMHO this edit (stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25587151) should not have been approved. Unfortunately, quite a few of this user's edits are like this.*

Comment: You mixed two things here. OP approving a bad edit and the editor doing bad edits. Two different flags with different expected/suggested outcomes would have been better, I guess.

Comment: @Tom This isn't about OP but about the editor who suggested it and got rep from it. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: That the flag was rejected does not mean that the mod thought the "edit was good" (or bad), but that they thought it didn't require moderator attention. Those are two different things and you should not conflate the two.

Comment: @yivi You sure about that? *a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it* sounds different to me.

Comment: If your flag wasn't about that OP, then the flag message is very misleading, because it starts with an action of them as a reviewer. If I were a mod, I would have thought you meant the reviewer shouldn't accept such edits and I should notify them.

Comment: @yivi I changed that in the question. It seemed like a generic message and not something they typed up so I didn't mention it.

Comment: It is a generic message, but it still has a meaning :P

Comment: Yes, it's a generic message that means what I explained before. That they thought that the case didn't require moderator intervention. You shouldn't read anything about that specific edit in the flag rejection.

Comment: folks who wrote above that it didn't require mod attention are all wrong, decline message clearly indicates that moderator picked different reason: "found no evidence to support it". If your flag message didn't refer to other cases of user persistently suggesting harmful edits this could cause a decline with mentioned reason

Comment: @gnat I'm not saying I agree with the decline. I'm just saying that reading that the mod thought that that particular edit was OK, and to try to use that as a data point in suggested edit reviewing, is not correct. I don't believe the a mod would have thought that edit was correct.

Comment: A review is a suggestive view of a person, that may o r not be the view of you or the moderator, but it cannot be wrong, because that would be a objective review, and that is impossible. You are right to flag this so that a moderator checks if the user has made  more of such edits and ban them from editing

Comment: @nbk There are wrong reviews, according to the rules of the site. There are users suspended from review all the time (automatically and manually) for reviewing wrongly.

Comment: @yivi i was banned for a week, because a moderator didn't agree with me, so i know that from experience. I got yesterday a question which i didn't want to reopen, because the question was stupid, and had only comments with a solution to a stupid question, but it had 10 upvotes for c# tostring date formatting. I don't understand your review system, it is based on check and balances and still you punish people for having a different opinion, the revie system needs a urgent Revision

Comment: @nbk There are no punishments in the review queues. At most, there are suspensions. But it's not a punishment, it's just a way to stop users from reviewing incorrectly. Since reviewing is work and not a reward, temporarily preventing users from reviewing can't be seen as punishment in any way. And the site has rules, yes. If a user disagrees with the rules and behaves in way inconsistent with the rules, there are some ways to try to limit the damage. Disagreement with the rules is never (in Stack Overflow or elsewhere) enough to avoid the rules from applying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I declined the flag for two reasons:

- The edit was accepted by the post owner, they have a veto on such suggested edits. They are clearly a newer, inexperienced account that did not otherwise had suggested edit review rights. They didn't 'review' as much as just accepted an edit to their own post. This is not indicative of a systemic failure to reject suggested edits.
- while that specific edit may not have been the best quality, overall that user is not making terrible edits. In fact, many of their recent suggested edits were correctly approved.

Since neither point in your flag applied, I declined the flag with the standard 'no evidence found to support it' reason.

Comment: Not disagreeing with your assessment, but the editor in question is doing a bunch of unnecessary bolding.

Comment: @psubsee2003: yes, agreed, but the other post where they did this they also corrected typos. They don't do this on most posts, and they do so in a pattern: 'labels' for code blocks. That, to me, looks like a genuine attempt at improving the post, however misplaced the actual style.

Comment: Yup, you are roight.  Just pointing out the bolding issue

Comment: [1/2] Thank you for the clarification. Apparently my understanding of good edits fundamentally differs from the moderation's understanding. In my opinion, the edit I flagged is of terrible quality and either shows a clear misunderstanding of when an edit should be suggested or is a blatant attempt of gaining rep. Additionally, the edit history of the user is full of questionable edits that brush over obvious errors with some chance of correcting (sometimes from British to American English) a few spelling errors while introducing random formatting.

Comment: [2/2] The fact that the user stopped editing after exactly 500 edits (gold badge + maximum rep gain) doesn't help either. However, I respect your authority on this subject and will refrain from reviewing suggested edits in the future. Thank you for taking the time to address this issue.

Comment: @leonheess please do review suggested edits! It’s just that this user wasn’t *so* bad that it required moderator intervention.

Comment: @leonheess I disagree, however, that their formatting attempts are *random*.

Comment: [Canonical on bold formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327171/6296561)

Comment: @Zoe the bolding wasn't *excessive* either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the problem is that what people consider **excessive** is subjective.